# Density of States of Free Electrons in a Magnetic Field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, density-of-states

In lectures we have been shown that the density of states (DOS) of 3D free electrons in a magnetic field is:

$$D(E) = \frac {m^\frac32}{\sqrt{2}\pi^2\hbar^2} \sum^{\nu_{max}}_{0} \frac {\hbar\omega_c}{\sqrt{E-\hbar\omega_c(\nu +\frac 12)}}$$

Now if the magnetic field were turned off (taking the limit $B \rightarrow0$) I imagine the relation should simplify to the standard DOS:

$$D(E) = \frac {\sqrt{2}m^\frac32}{\pi^2\hbar^2} E^{\frac 12}$$

But I don't really understand how this can happen. How can we go from our DOS $\sim E^{\frac{-1}{2}}$ to DOS $\sim E^{\frac 12}$? And from just looking at the expression I get the impression that it would go to $0$ as B goes to $0$.

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain it to me, thank you!

Comment: The point which makes it difficult to analyze this limit is that, as $B\to 0$, not only $\omega_c \sim B \to 0$, but also $\nu_{max} \sim 1/B \to \infty$. This happens because the degeneracy of each Landau level is proportional to $B$, thus when $B$ is small, the degeneracy is low and many more levels get occupied... This at leasts explains why the DOS does not vanish

Comment: Ah, I had not considered what happens to $v_{max}$ in the limit, I'm still confused as to how the energy term gets inverted but it's a start anyway!

Answer (score -1):

you can treat the summation part as an integration $dx=\hbar\omega$  and you will find the convergence.